# JavaScript Array destructuring assignment and null value

Tags: javascript

I'm using an external service `getListOfItemsFromServiceA` which accepts an `id` (of user) and returns a list of 5 items (exactly 5) associated to this user.

I used Array destructuring assignment to set the value of those items which is working fine like this (just an example):

```js
var item1, item2, item3, item4, item5;
//var result = getListOfItemsFromServiceA(1622);
var exampleResult = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'];
[item1, item2, item3, item4, item5] = exampleResult;
console.log(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5);
```

The problem I have is that in some cases `getListOfItemsFromServiceA(id)` returns `null` for example when the `id` is not found in the database. So my code is not working:

```js
var item1, item2, item3, item4, item5;
//var result = getListOfItemsFromServiceA(1622);
var exampleResult = null;
[item1, item2, item3, item4, item5] = exampleResult;
console.log(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5);
```

Is there a way to solve this using Array destructing syntax instead of adding an if condition like `if(getListOfItemsFromServiceA(1622) !== null)`?

Note

- I can't change the code of `getListOfItemsFromServiceA`.

Comment: why you don't want to add if condition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this:

```
[item1, item2, item3, item4, item5] = exampleResult || [];
```

Comment: Not very elegant in the sense that it produces `undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined`

Comment: I know, indeed. But perhaps this exactly what he wants.

Comment: True, OP asks "Is there a way to solve it?" and this solves it :)

Comment: @HenriqueOeckslerBertoldi thanks this is what I need. It works!

Answer (score 3):

You can add a fallback if exampleResult is null :

```js
var item1, item2, item3, item4, item5;
var exampleResult = null;
[item1, item2, item3, item4, item5] = exampleResult || [];
console.log(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5);
```

This produces `undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined`.

You can also set default values to the destructured variables :

```js
var item1, item2, item3, item4, item5;
var exampleResult = null;
[item1="", item2="", item3="", item4="", item5=""] = exampleResult || [];
    console.log(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5);
```