# Is there any concise way to set default value to null when using Javascript Destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

These two version isn't 100% the same, when value is `null` the result is different:

```
// version 1
const dogs = animal.dogs || [];
const cats = animal.cats || [];

// version 2
const { dogs = [], cats = [] } = animal;
```

Since version 1 is a lot tedious, so I want to know is there any concise way to archive this effect.

---

To be more specific, assumming that `animal` comes from api, and its value could be `animal: { dogs: ['some kind of dog'], cats: ['some kind of cat'] }` or `animal: { dogs: null, cats: null }`

I want to assign value `[]` to `dog` or `cat` when its value is `null`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to destructure nested object with null value using default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108874/how-to-destructure-nested-object-with-null-value-using-default-value)

Comment: If there is no new way around in the four years (which I could not find), the accepted answer to this question tells there's no shortcut: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39522014/4636715

Comment: Do you want the value to be null or [] ?  Do these snippets help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48433029/3825777 or this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45210379/3825777 or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105782/javascript-array-destructuring-assignment-and-null-value